# Livedata causing recyclerview to update causing lose in edittext focus

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to implement a cart view, in which the user can look up the products he has chose and can edit its quantity. For storage, I am using Room and observing the livedata from database. I am using focus change listener on EditText(s) and updating quantity when the edittext lose focus. The problem I am facing is that whenever I click any edittext, the first edittext gets in focus.

```
dashboardViewModel.cartProducts.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, object: Observer<List<Product?>> {

            override fun onChanged(t: List<Product?>?) {
                t?.let {
                    Log.d(TAG,"${it.size}")
                    fragmentDashboardBinding.cartRecycler.apply {
                    val recyclerViewState = fragmentDashboardBinding.cartRecycler.layoutManager?.onSaveInstanceState()
                    adapter = CartAdapter(it)
                    fragmentDashboardBinding.cartRecycler.layoutManager?.onRestoreInstanceState(recyclerViewState)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

```
 binding.apply {
                viewModel?.cartItem = cartItem
                binding.cartProductQuantity.setOnFocusChangeListener(object: View.OnFocusChangeListener{
                    override fun onFocusChange(v: View?, hasFocus: Boolean) {
                       if(!hasFocus){
                           cartItem?.quantity = if(binding.cartProductQuantity.text.toString()==""){0}else{binding.cartProductQuantity.text.toString().toInt()}
                           dashboardViewModel.updateProduct(cartItem!!)
                       }
                    }

                })
                executePendingBindings()
            }
```